# Why isn't there an HTML tag to diminish content?

Tags: html

Yesterday I was building a template for a newspage.
I wanted a `<h2>` that contains the date of the news item. Since I wanted the date to be less important than the rest of the text in the `<h2>` I went looking for an HTML tag that can semantically diminish content. But this doesn't exist.

So why isn't there something like a `<dim>` (*diminish tag*) tag that is more or less a negative of the `<em>` tag?

Comment: the `<small>` tag is deprecated since HTML4 and completely removed from HTML5, if I'm not mistaken. It has no semantic value.

Comment: I don't see `small` removed from HTML5. It has new semantics though.

Comment: You're right Ionuț G. Stan, I read it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people using the [`small`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element) tag for this kind of semantics.

What I've used before was [`time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) with a [`pubdate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#attr-time-pubdate) attribute. That should satisfy the semantics even more.

Answer (score 0):

markup:

```
<span class="dim">content</span>
```

css:

```
.dim{font-size:0.9em}
```

That combination should allow the font-size to get gradually smaller as the tags are nested deeper. From the browser's point of view it's semantically meaningless but it's an OK first step.

Answer (score 0):

if it is less important than `h2` it should be wrapped in `h3` or lower. use `css` to style it.

but not nested....

Comment: But `<h3>` is a header on itself, it's different from an element that contains diminished content relative to its context.
In my particular example it could be a good fix, but it doesn't quite answer my question :)